# Bug: Cannot edit hints/warnings in BPL project options

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I took advantage of the (time limited) upgrade offer I received via email from Embarcadero and upgraded to Delphi XE7. I like it. Good versions like this appear ever 7 years :)

But I have a problem: I don't know how to silence some warnings. For example 'W1011 Text after final END'. The 'Project Options' box is different. All those editable values are gone. Instead I have 3 entries like 'Value from: Debug configuration - All platforms.'

Where I can configure the global "Debug configuration - All platforms" thing?

[image]

Comment: @Altar I edited the question title - now we know what the problem is describing it precisely there will help people in future find this question.

Comment: In the meantime I guess you can still apply settings using the .dproj file.

Comment: @DavidM - In the light of the new discovered bug, it is a good idea to add 'BPL' in the title.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I edited my answer to include the .dproj file. You're right, it's probably the correct or best way, although more difficult to avoid making errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: Updated after the screenshot. Old answer below labeled 'General projects' since it's still useful in the general case, for EXEs, DLLs, etc.

## BPL projects in XE7 only (okay in XE6-, fixed in XE8+)

Update: this bug has been [marked as resolved in XE8](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9890).

I see in your screenshot you have a BPL project open (btw, you're using the XE2 Graphics32 package in XE7 - better to use the dedicated XE7 one.)

**I can verify that BPLs do not show the list of warnings and hints the way other project types do.** EXEs, DLLs, etc list them, as below. I think this is [a bug: RSP-8980.](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9890) It is a **regression from XE6**; XE6 shows the hints and warnings as expected but XE7 does not.

**Edit the DPROJ manually**

David Heffernan points out that these options are supposed to be in the project, even though the UI isn't letting you edit them. One way would be to create another project (eg a DLL), set up the options as you need, and edit the BPL's project file (.dproj) manually to include them, copying from the correctly set up other project.

This is complicated - it's XML, you need to get all the named configurations exactly right, etc - but will mimic what the UI does for you.

**BPK file**

You can workaround this by specifying them in the .bpk file itself. You can see a number of project options are in the GR32 .bpk file:

[image: A new BPL project's BPK file]

The BPK is analogous to the DPR file, only for BPLs. To find this file, right-click the BPL project and click 'View Source'.

If you add the line

```
{$WARN GARBAGE OFF}
```

and rebuild (not recompile, but build) the project, you will see all units which previously showed warning W1011 now do not.

How do you know what a particular warning is called, when you have to refer to them by name not number? Look them up on [this handy blog post](http://marc.durdin.net/2012/05/delphi-xe2s-hidden-hints-and-warnings-options/).

I have added two Quality bug reports:

- [Allow hints and warnings to be referring to in compiler directives by number, not just name](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9889)
- [Packages do not allow hints/warnings to be set in the Project Options the way other project types do](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9890)

## General projects

A project has a number of [targets](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Target_Options) (such as Windows 32bit Debug, vs OSX 32bit Release, etc) and setting can be set for each of those. In addition, these settings are inheritable, so you can set settings for all debug targets, all release targets, etc.

In general, you should set a setting at the highest level possible, and override at the most specific level.

With that as background, to change `W1011 Text after final end` open the Project Options and navigate to the Hints and Warnings section. In the 'Target' dropdown combo at the top, choose the highest-level target where you want to make the change (for example, in this screenshot I've chosen 'Debug configuration - all platforms' which means that Win32 Debug and Win64 Debug and any other platform debug will use this setting with the value specified here.)

Expand the 'Output warnings' tree and ignore the dark red 'Value from Foo' nodes which are referring to the inherited values - it's impossible to use here and makes more sense for other settings. These are the ones that I think are confusing you, from your question. Instead, scroll down until you see 'Text after final end' (warnings are sorted alphabetically.)

[image: Project Options, with a specific warning selection]

Select it, and choose the option you're interested in.

Key things to avoid confusion:

- Options are inherited
- Use the combo box at the top to select the level at which you are applying the setting
- Override at the most specific possible
- Set at the most generic possible
- When setting a value, ignore the dark red "Value from Foo" inherited nodes; just scroll down or expand, and set the setting you want

Comment: Thanks for your nice and well documented answer. I update my question with a screenshot so show that there is nothing I can expand.

Comment: I checked the web site for Graphics32 and the latest update is few years old. No support for XE7 yet.

Comment: I already did the {$WARN GARBAGE OFF} trick but this is not my actual problem. My problem is that I cannot see/edit ANY options for my projects (as you can see in my screenshots)!! Is it a bug or I don't know how to reach those values? In your screenshot you can see them all.

Comment: Are you using the latest checkout from SVN? It's been updated for XE7. Published packages might not have been for a while. svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/graphics32/code/trunk/Source

Comment: I've updated the answer. For BPLs, you can't do it this way. No idea why. I'd say a bug, or certainly very inconvenient. Instead, you have to do it in the BPK file.

Comment: So, you CANNOT see the options also for a BPL project? In this case is not a bug/problem specific to my computer but a bug in Delphi XE7. AND A BIG BUG!

Comment: Agreed. Not good, and not what I expected. [I filed a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-9890). Please feel free to vote for it.

Comment: Yey! My first hour with Delphi XE7 and I step into a pretty bug. Lucky me :)

Comment: Indeed :D I have been using it for some time and hadn't noticed it before. Have you installed update 1, by any chance? (Also, XE6 doesn't show this bug, so it's a regression.)

Comment: Yes. I have Update 1 installed.

Comment: I have also re-discovered a bug that haunted me in Delphi XE: 100% core utilization when I edit a DPR file! The bug is still here in XE7.

Comment: You don't mean .bpk file. I think you mean .dpk. However, I think these settings are intended to reside in the .dproj file.

Comment: I suppose you could manually edit the .dproj file too. It's a lot less user-friendly / accessible though. That's why the UI needs to work :/

Comment: @DavidM Obviously the UI should work. But in the meantime, it's probably best to edit the .dproj file because when the UI is fixed in a future release, the settings will be in the same place as if they had been put there by the UI.